# Unable to change port or host/server, c#

Tags: c#, server, client, port

I am currently making a client and server. The server will store people and their location using a dictionary. The client can then lookup a location or update/add a person and their location. For example, I could type 'Lucy', 'School', and the server will add that to the dictionary. If I then type 'Lucy' it should reply with 'School' and if I type in 'Lucy' 'Home' it should up date that to the dictionary.

However, in the arguments, the user may put /h followed by a host name and /p followed by a port number. I'm currently trying to implement this feature in the client, however it doesn't seem to be working at all.

The following is my code. I made a list for the arguments so that if it does have /h or /p followed by the appropriate information, I can reduce the number of arguments so it doesn't effect the other parts of the program.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    String server = "whois.networksolutions.com";
    int port = 43;

    List<string> list = new List<string>(args);

    for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
    {
        if (args[i].Trim() == "/h")
        {
            string serverString = args[i + 1].Trim();
            server = args[i + 1];
            list.RemoveAt(i);
            //remove h from the list
            list.RemoveAt(i);
            //remove server name from the lst
            args = list.ToArray();
            //update args array
            i = i - 1;
            Console.WriteLine("Server changed to " + serverString);
        }

        else if (args[i].Trim() == "/p")
        {
            string portString = args[i + 1];
            port = Convert.ToInt32(args[i + 1].Trim());
            list.RemoveAt(i);
            //remove p from the list
            list.RemoveAt(i);
            //remover port number from list
            args = list.ToArray();
            //update args array
            i = i - 1;
            Console.WriteLine("Port changed to " + portString);
        }
    }


    try
    {
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
        client.Connect(server, port);
        client.ReceiveTimeout = 1000;
        client.SendTimeout = 1000;
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
        sw.AutoFlush = true;
        sw.WriteLine(args[0]);


        if (args.Length == 1)
        {
            if (args[0] == "514872")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("514872 is being tested\r\n");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR: no entries found\r\n");
            }
        }
        else if (args.Length == 2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(args[0] + " location changed to be is being tested\r\n");
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Connection failure.");
    }
}
```

}

Any help would be massively appreciated!

Thank you
Lucy

Comment: Hi, i do not understand what is your exact problem with that code.
Do you get any kind of Exception, when your Code is running?

Comment: Hi, it's just coming up with connection failed, I have checked the server and that isn't the problem

Comment: Try to change your catch to:

catch(Exception e){
 Console.WriteLine("Connection failure.");
 Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}

you could also set a breakpoint and see what exact kind of exception is thrown.  That will give u a hint.

Comment: Its saying too many arguments now looking likes it not deleting it from the list